# Как получить аккаунт продавца?

Tags: android

Здравствуйте, в панели разработчика android у меня не получается настроить аккаунт продавца так как я из Казахстана - а этой страны нет в списке партнеров гугл.

Как мне обновить мой аккаунт до продавца?
Говорят, надо съездить в Россию и там открыть счет например в сбербанке, но даже если я это сделаю то что дальше? мне чел один говорил что он зашел в гугл кошелек и там у него есть пункт: "настройки продавца" - дело в том что в моем гугл кошельке нет такого пункта((( даже если я открою счет в России то что делать дальше? где поменять настройки так чтоб гугл думал что я в России???

Comment: Официально - только дождаться, когда Google позволит из Казахстана быть "продавцом". Я сам с Украины и у меня подобная проблема.

Comment: ну можно же наврено катко открыть счет в россии и гдето поменять данные аккаунта гугл на россию?

Answer (score 2):

Не сможете, гугль не дурак, по айпи адресу видит, что соединение идет из Казахстана и не будет вам показывать настройки консоли как для России. Можно наверное как-то извратиться через прокси - не пробовал, не скажу. Но все равно вряд ли. Во всем что касается бабок Гугль все очень тщательно прорабатывает и "дырок" не оставляет.

Советую сконцентироваться на модели рекламной модели продаж - Adware, благо площадок таких много.